# What is the function and/or meaning of the 2 '以‘ in this phrase?

Tags: usage

I came across this phrase but I cannot really see the function or point of the 2 '以‘。 Must be old Chinese.

授人以鱼不如授人以渔。 (Translated maybe: "Knowledge is the best charity.")

What are the 2 '以‘ doing here please?

Comment: baike:    It's better to teach a man fishing than to give him fish.   授某人以某事 give/teach so. sth.

Comment: look up 以 in dictionaries, e.g. ＂汉语水平考试词典＂，［义４］表示给与等意义（用在动词后（used after a verb to indicate "give" etc.):借～｜致～｜六乘～三是十八｜给劳动模范～表扬

Comment: 谢谢。你的意思是这样‘授。。。以。。。‘，‘授。。。以。。。‘在一起合作？？

Comment: ？？？ A 不如 B，A not equal to，not as good as，inferior to  B，B would be better than A

Comment: I understand 不如 quite well.  My question is, 'What is 以 doing here? I cannot find 授以 as a word， but you say 以 indicates 'give'. Are you saying ‘授’ and '以‘ are in combination?授人以鱼 is ‘give a man give a fish' is that your meaning? For an old use of 以 I find:文言连词，与“而”用法相同：梦寐～求。

Comment: as 2nd comment says, 以 after verbs of giving, providing etc. like 借、致，给 introduces the object that is given to the person, V 某人 以 某事 corresponds to English V with indirect object so./ 某人 and direct object sth./ 某事 （in case of ditransitive E verb), or V sth./某事  to  so./ 某人。Again，

给A以B，give A B ，give B to A，similarly for other verbs of type 给

Comment: should have read comment more carefully, answering comment #6 again, no it is not "my meaning" 授 means teach, with direct object 人, 以 introduces the thing that is being taught 渔 fishing, not 鱼 fish, also the examples in comment #2 (copied from dictionary) explain
the use of 以 （perhaps not the English text)

Comment: That is why I think the 2 以 may not be the same: 授人以鱼 and 授人以渔， but if we assume 以 is 把： 把鱼授人不如把渔教人。Below I was told 以 is 'with', but that doesn't really work, in English anyway. I get the feeling, 以 is used more for rhythm than meaning. Chinese likes 4 characters.

Comment: ?that is why? According to baike's translation do the 2 以 not play the same role?   给某人以某事，give so. sth., give sth. to so. 授某人以某事 teach so. sth., teach sth. to so.(授 to teach，to instruct，to award，to give),   以 may correspond to "with",in the case of "provide with, supply" 给（pronounced jǐ)  给以 provide with

Answer (score 2):

**以** means "**with**" here

[授人(give people)] [**以**  **(with)**] [鱼 (fish)] [不如 (not as good as)] [授人 (teach people)] [**以**  **(with)** ] [渔 (lessons of fishing)]

- 授 can mean "to give" or " to teach"
- 鱼 is noun for "fish"
- 渔 is verb for "to fish"

授人以鱼不如授人以渔 = " It is better to teach someone to fish than give someone fish. "

Comment: '以 is 'with'?? How do you figure that? Where did you get that from?

Comment: http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/461/  definition 4

Comment: Example: 待人**以**誠，(treat people **with** sincerity); **以**仁治天下 ( govern the world **with** kindness) ;  **以**文會友 (make friends **with** written works) ; **以**武力反抗 ( resist **with** force)

Comment: Thanks, that is very interesting! And thanks for the link, I'd never heard of that dictionary! I don't think I would use 'with' each time, but the idea is great! But you would not translate '授人以鱼‘ as 'give person with fish' I think!

Comment: How about " donate with fish"? similar to " donate with your own money." "with" here basically means " using"

Answer (score 1):

i guess the sentence "授人以魚不如授人以漁" is translated, pretending in the style of literary chinese, from the quote

```
"give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day.
 teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime"
```

which is derived from anne isabella's writing; here's the link to the investigation:

http://quoteinvestigator.com/2015/08/28/fish/

imo, it's marginally acceptable. the original quote could be translated without 以, e.g.:

```
授之魚未若教之漁
```

added another translation:

```
授之魚﹒苟延而已﹒未若教之漁﹒裨益一生
```

have fun :)

added info:

```
What if I rewrite "授人以鱼不如授人以渔“ as "把鱼授人不如把渔教人“? 
It is not as poetic, but is it the same or completely wrong?
If acceptable, we have 以 is 把。
```

把魚授人 is OK; but 把漁教人, imo, is unacceptable. the least change of it is

```
把魚授人不如教人以漁
```

as i said before in another comment, that with 10 characters only, 3 of them (魚, 如, 漁) have similar pronunciation is not good, better to avoid it.

in **literary chinese**, "以" has numerous usages. let's use 教人以漁 as an example:

if you keep the sequence, it could be interpreted as

```
teaching (教) someone (人) to fish (漁)
```

以 serves the purpose of make it 4 letters long; however, it's not possible to omit 以, "教人漁" is odd.

next, if you change the sequence to 以漁教人, it could be interpreted as

```
using (以) fishing techniques (漁) to teach (教) people (人)
```

that, 以 has the meaning of 用. both of them are correct.

Comment: Basically, 以 is there to make a 4 character couplet, favoured by Chinese writers, is that what you are saying?

Comment: if you start by "授人", it's yes, you need "以" to make it to 4 characters long. cause "授人魚" is odd / wrong, in literary chinese.

Comment: Since 授之魚未若教之漁 is not a poem, I would say it is a correctly constructed phrase in classical writing style.  I would go further and write:  "授魚不如教漁"

Comment: well, the main reason that i use 未若 is: 魚 sounds similar to 如, with such few characters, 3 of them with alike pronunciation is, erhhh, better to avoid this situation. "授魚" & "教漁" is odd, the "之" cannot be omitted here. try again :)

Comment: What if I rewrite "授人以鱼不如授人以渔“ as "把鱼授人不如把渔教人“? It is not as poetic, but is it the same or completely wrong? If acceptable, we have 以 is 把。

Comment: @gangosa, i edited the answer, it's hard to write long answer in comment :(